# RPi + NetBeans debugging and Hello World

Tags: debugging, netbeans, printf

Currently I work with RPi2 and remote connection to NetBeans 8.1 on my laptop.
I can write programs, run it, debug it and go step-by-step through the lines. This tutorial helps me to setup this: [Installing NetBeans For C++ Remote Development on A Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/programming-in-c/compilers-and-ides/netbeans-windows/installing-netbeans-for-c-remote-development-on-a-raspberry-pi)

First test: I tried a simple "Hello World" program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(void)
{
  int i = 0;

  printf("Hallo World!\n");
  i++;
  printf("Hallo World!\n");
  i++;
  printf("Hallo World!\n");
  i++;
  printf("Hallo World!\n");
  i++;
}
```

and debug it stepwise with NetBeans. Result: Variable i increments fine, but **no printf output** comes up! If I run the program without debugging, all works fine. I tried additional fflush and so on but nothing works.

What way can I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found he answer by myself...

First: Disable buffering by

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL);   // disable buffering on stdout
```

Next: Setup the project  by: Right Click on the project name > Properties > Categories = "Run" and here Console type = "Standard output".

This works for me with stepwise debug every printf line-per-line.

Mike.F.